# Export changeset from TFS?

Tags: version-control

Before we migrated to Team Foundation Server we had SVN to manage our source code, with TortoiseSVN as client software.

Back then, when we completed a new feature in the project, you could choose the revision where you started with the feature and compare it with head revision.

Then you could export all the files that changed, with maintained folder structure. And then we could upload only the affected files and folders to production environment.

Is it possible to do something similar to this with TFS?

Comment: Why not actually build the code you want to deploy, then deploy from the build results?

Comment: Yes, it might be my mindset thats wrong, the problem may be that im still "thinking SVN"...

I want to upload only the affected files to production, not the entire solution.

Comment: Is this what your QA tests? "The affected files"? Do a build, deploy the build to QA, test it, and when it passes, deploy the same build to production. This will not include the source files, only content and binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One avenue to explorer is writing a script around the "get changeset" functionality in the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963).  This will allow you to get all the files in a specific changeset.  You could iterate over the changesets between the original changeset and the changeset to push to production, running **getchangeset** for each, and then push the results up.